# PHP CSSTidy throwing warning unexpectedly

Tags: php, css, minify, csstidy

So I have a [CSS file](https://gist.github.com/pretty/68dcc0f4779b1fbb80f9) which I am running through [PHP CSSTidy](https://github.com/Cerdic/CSSTidy) with the following setup.

```
require_once './application/helpers/csstidy/class.csstidy.php';

$css = new csstidy();
$css->set_cfg('remove_last_;',TRUE);
$css->set_cfg('compress_colors',TRUE);
$css->set_cfg('template', 'highest');

$css->parse(strip_tags($content));
$content = $css->print->plain();
```

It *seems* to work, but I get a notice **twice** like so:

```
Severity: Notice  --> Uninitialized string offset: -1 /application/helpers/csstidy/class.csstidy.php 1035
Severity: Notice  --> Uninitialized string offset: -1 /application/helpers/csstidy/class.csstidy.php 1035
```

Which is [this](https://github.com/Cerdic/CSSTidy/blob/master/class.csstidy.php#L1035) line.

I have no idea why this is happening, the CSS is valid... any ideas? I don't want to mute the notice/warning unnecessarily.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

In case you missed it [this is the link to the CSS file](https://gist.github.com/pretty/68dcc0f4779b1fbb80f9).